# Remotely force kill a shared ngrok session forwarding a React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ngrok

I share an ngrok account with my coworkers. We are using it to develop a React application (`npx create-react-app`). We are all using UNIX-like systems. Quite often I go to spin up an http tunnel and I am met with the message

```sh
Your account '*****@*********.com' is limited to 1 simultaneous ngrok client session.
Active ngrok client sessions in region 'us':
  - ******************************** (**.***.***.***)

ERR_NGROK_108
```

Or if I am logged in with my own account, but trying to use the same tunnel, I get

```sh
The tunnel 'https://*****.ngrok.io' is already bound to another 
tunnel session

ERR_NGROK_334
```

Both of these messages mean my coworker (who I know for a fact is currently asleep) left their ngrok session running. I would like to execute a simple command that tells their system to kill ngrok processes.

##### Is there an ngrok CLI command to force kill a session running on another machine?

Based on my research so far, I think the answer is no. But please tell me if I am wrong.

##### Is there a safe way to remotely execute a system command to kill ngrok sessions?

I found a beautiful solution that some Rails developers came up with to [remotely kill ngrok sessions in a Rails API](https://blog.fomo.com/remotely-kill-ngrok-session/).

Their strategy is to include an API endpoint (only in development mode) that executes the system command `killall ngrok` to kill all ngrok processes on that system.

##### Is there a way to remotely execute system commands with our client-side rendered React application?

My gut tells me no, at least not without spinning up a server to receive the kill request.

My thought is, maybe I can create a proxy server for my React application using Node and Express. That server can do exactly two things: act as a proxy to the React app, and kill ngrok when it receives a specific request. In the past I have built a proxy server in the same git repository as my React app, so I think this solution is attainable.

##### How would you recommend I move forward?

So far I have not been able to find an example of this online. I would hate to waste my time building a low quality version of something that already exists.

I see there is an [ngrok npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok)... maybe that could be useful.

Any thoughts on best practices when configuring/coding the proxy server are much appreciated.

Or if you think I am overcomplicating things, let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ngrok now has [a beta API](https://ngrok.com/docs/api#api-tunnel-sessions-stop) (for paid plans only I believe?) that can remotely stop agents. Their [dashboard](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/tunnels/agents) now also offers the same functionality, even if you are not part of the beta.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is to login into your ngrok account (https://dashboard.ngrok.com/login) and then, using the Agents option in the menu, you can close all or any session that is currently active:

[image]